# vb.net button visibility based on checkbox

Tags: vb.net, button, checkbox

So i have a form as below:

```
Public Class IPADSOFT

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    IPADSOFTTS.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    HOME.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```

which has 3 checkboxes labeled IPADSOFTBOX1, IPADSOFTBOX2, IPADSOFTBOX3
So... i have another form as follows:

```
Public Class IPADSOFTTS
Private Sub onload()
    If IPADSOFT.IPADSOFTBOX1.Checked Then
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button5.Visible = True

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    HOME.Show()
    IPADSOFT.Hide()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub
End Class
```

Now the idea is that all the buttons on that second form are set to visible-false and i want the page to check which checkboxes are checked on the last form  and then make the required buttons on this form visible... but it isnt working

What am i doing wrong?? i apologise im very very new to vb.net

Comment: That `onload` method in your second form will not be called by magic.  If you want something done when a form loads then you need to handle the `Load` event handler of that form.  Also, should you not have three `If` blocks if you want to test three different `CheckBoxes`?  Finally, that `If` statement will only work if the first form is the default instance of its type. Is it?  How was it displayed in the first place? If it's the startup form for the project then it is a default instance.

Comment: so how would i handle the load event and also no its not the default instance. so do i then have to reference the previous form and how would i go about that.

Comment: "how would i handle the load event"  What do you not understand about the information you found on that subject when you searched the web?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. english is not my native language. if i found anything that i understood on the web i would not be asking for help. if you arent prepared to help then dont comment. comments like your last are not helpful and unneeded. i probably know what you mean but maybe i dont know it as "handling the load event" so please explain it to me... i said i am very very new to VB.net in my OP and its a small project in private. sorry i am not good enough for your help

Comment: I did help. I told you that you needed to handle the `Load` event. That's information that you didn't have before. Use it. Have you searched the web on that topic specifically? I'll wager not, given that you commented three minutes after I did.

Comment: at the time of my question asking how i would handle then no i hadnt, but i have since... everything i keep finding makes no sense to what it all mewans

Comment: i also was not clear in my OP, i know i need three if blocks for three checkboxes but the code is not complete i was testing it on just the first checkbox and once i have it working i will be adding the other two blocks

Comment: I just searched for "vb.net handle form load event" and the very first result was the MSDN documentation for that event and it includes a code example that shows handlers for several events including `Load`.  What exactly did you search for that you couldn't find that? It continues to amaze me that, as information get easier to find, people get proportionally worse at finding it. Are you aware that the code you posted includes handlers for the `Click` events of several `Buttons`? If not then that's part of the problem: you haven't spent enough time learning the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the second form with this

```
Dim newForm As New IPADSOFTTS With
            {.MainForm = Me}
            newForm .Show()
```

Set `Public MainForm As IPADSOFT` below the `Public Class` of second form

Then use in the Load event

```
if MainForm.IPADSOFTBOX1.Checked = true then
                        'Do whatever
                        End if
```